# How do I make the y-axis intersect the x-axis at 0 in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to make Y axis cross X axis at 0 and show labels in the middle of graph using chart.js plugin ?

Now it looks like this:

[image: current]

I want it too look something like this:

[image: What i want]

My [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9L3sprt/) / snippet

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      label: 'Linear',
      data: ['-3', '-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
    }],
    labels: ['-3', '-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          weight: 100,
          suggestedMin: -5,
          suggestedMax: 5,

          stepSize: 1
        },
        plotLines: {
          value: 0,
          width: 2,
          color: 'blue'
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do the workaround by setting padding for yAxis:

```
        scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                position: top,
                beginAtZero: false,
                padding: -225,
                weight :500,
                stepSize: 1
            }


        }],
```

[image: padding]

Hope it will help someone.